# Custom marker icons in Google Static Map URL don't show up

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-static-api

I can't figure out why my custom marker icons are not all showed on this map below despite that all icons exist... You can test. That's so strange...

=> [Google map static url](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=48.87025346967912,2.3016147060156955&zoom=14&size=640x480&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCFPa5pLOcNemHsGsze4JH99L3LFdDP7ro&markers=icon:http://163.172.203.135/LogiMapIPSODEV/appliweb/images/icones/c/339966/0.png|48.87566835,2.30265564000001&markers=icon:http://163.172.203.135/LogiMapIPSODEV/appliweb/images/icones/c/339966/1.png|48.8684793,2.32860541000002&markers=icon:http://163.172.203.135/LogiMapIPSODEV/appliweb/images/icones/c/339966/2.png|48.87416534,2.32446073999995&markers=icon:http://163.172.203.135/LogiMapIPSODEV/appliweb/images/icones/c/339966/3.png|48.86950707,2.30266822999999&markers=icon:http://163.172.203.135/LogiMapIPSODEV/appliweb/images/icones/c/993366/4.png|48.8656349,2.30572470000004&markers=icon:http://163.172.203.135/LogiMapIPSODEV/appliweb/images/icones/c/339966/5.png|48.8733364,2.3192377&markers=icon:http://163.172.203.135/LogiMapIPSODEV/appliweb/images/icones/c/993366/6.png|48.8682729069271,2.28976740052485&markers=icon:http://163.172.203.135/LogiMapIPSODEV/appliweb/images/icones/c/339966/7.png|48.87401952,2.32959632999996&markers=icon:http://163.172.203.135/LogiMapIPSODEV/appliweb/images/icones/c/993366/8.png|48.872405898167,2.33810026090146&markers=icon:http://163.172.203.135/LogiMapIPSODEV/appliweb/images/icones/c/993366/9.png|48.86990999,2.33637060000001&markers=icon:http://163.172.203.135/LogiMapIPSODEV/appliweb/images/icones/c/993366/10.png|48.8735219,2.33895243999996&markers=icon:http://163.172.203.135/LogiMapIPSODEV/appliweb/images/icones/c/339966/11.png|48.873926,2.29947870000001&markers=icon:http://163.172.203.135/LogiMapIPSODEV/appliweb/images/icones/c/339966/12.png|48.87438023,2.30739684000002&markers=icon:http://163.172.203.135/LogiMapIPSODEV/appliweb/images/icones/c/993366/13.png|48.87066614,2.33260515000006&markers=icon:http://163.172.203.135/LogiMapIPSODEV/appliweb/images/icones/c/c00000/14.png|48.8765943,2.3137481&markers=icon:http://163.172.203.135/LogiMapIPSODEV/appliweb/images/icones/c/993366/15.png|48.86630028,2.30421562000004&markers=icon:http://163.172.203.135/LogiMapIPSODEV/appliweb/images/icones/c/339966/16.png|48.86500988,2.30957964999993&markers=icon:http://163.172.203.135/LogiMapIPSODEV/appliweb/images/icones/c/993366/17.png|48.8724821094975,2.30064739232785&markers=icon:http://163.172.203.135/LogiMapIPSODEV/appliweb/images/icones/c/993366/18.png|48.87719,2.31000470000004&markers=icon:http://163.172.203.135/LogiMapIPSODEV/appliweb/images/icones/c/339966/19.png|48.8682787,2.30993660000001&markers=icon:http://163.172.203.135/LogiMapIPSODEV/appliweb/images/icones/c/339966/20.png|48.86607848,2.2867347300000347&markers=icon:http://163.172.203.135/LogiMapIPSODEV/appliweb/images/icones/c/339966/21.png|48.8730255534459,2.29783433439331&markers=icon:http://163.172.203.135/LogiMapIPSODEV/appliweb/images/icones/c/339966/22.png|48.87458158,2.30443156000001&markers=icon:http://163.172.203.135/LogiMapIPSODEV/appliweb/images/icones/c/993366/23.png|48.87414412,2.32399104000001&markers=icon:http://163.172.203.135/LogiMapIPSODEV/appliweb/images/icones/c/993366/24.png|48.8730717,2.3007053)

Comment: Read the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#CustomIcons

Comment: Is there any way to bypass that ? :/ Does the google static map api premium service allow more than 5 icons ?

Answer (score 3):

As this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5024859/5348277)  said:

> Static Maps service allows up to **five** unique custom icons per
>   request.  Note that each of these unique icons may be used multiple
>   times within the static map.

Comment: Is there any way to bypass that ? :/ Does the google static map api premium service allow more than 5 icons ?

Answer (score 3):

This is an official answer from Google regarding possibility to have more than 5 custom icons:

> Increasing the number of custom icons would increase the overall latency of the API requests, as the icons each take their own time to be fetched. [Issue 207](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35817020) (KML support) or other layer-rendering solutions would be a more robust solution: you can have KML + many icons in a KMZ file, which only needs 1 outbound request to fetch it.

You can see this explanation here:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35825584

Feel free to add star in the feature request for KML support in static maps to express your interest and subscribe to further notifications:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35817020

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get my PNG. I have to use either phantomJS to make a screenshot of the map or get the map without the KML (markers, polygons, etc...) with html2canvas then use Mercator's formula to convert lat/lng coords from markers to pixels and draw the KMLs with my custom icons on the canvas with JavaScript and send the picture from JS with canvas.toDataURL('image/png') to my Java code in base64 and decode it to upload the picture on the server....